# Reliable sources algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

"It turns out (surprise) the Internet is full of rumours and unreliable information." - Arnold Schwarzenegger

While some of this info can be analyzed "on the fly", like the one on this example, some other takes a while to trace back to one or more reliable sources.

I was thinking if it would be posible to make an autocheck algorithm, lets call it "BS tagger", which, implemented as a firefox plugin for example, could determine the veracity of a selected piece of text and authenticity matching it to its alleged author/source.

The first approach to implement this algorithm I could thought of was to do a simple google search and check the number of results, but it turns out (surprise) popularity and veracity/authenticity are not so strongly correlated.

Then I thought of something more elaborated: some kind of, let's call it "BSRank" algorithm, that works pretty much the same way, googling it and so, but only when it finds a "reliable" source reproducing the text it adds probability to its "veracity" (or authenticity, if it's just about checking an alleged Bob Dylan quote instead of an alleged original Coca-Cola formula).

Then I got stuck: Obviously to make this algorithm work I need 2 things:

-A dynamic "white list" of reliable sources.

-Some algorithm to identify and rank this sources, webrep style, but even more complex than that, since one web can have many users or authors publishing and one should not give the same credibility to all of them just because they're publishing next to each other.

So the algorithm inside the algorithm is the real hard trick here. My doubts are so generic I don't even know if they belong here but I would really appreciate some input: Any suggestions? Does anybody see a better approach to solve this problem or any related projects or can recomend me some good literature on the topic? Do you think this can be done with the resources of a student in his spare time or is it too much of a project for a rookie programmer?

Comment: The trouble is in today's world of shrinking budgets, even "reliable sources" like the NY Times sometimes "fact check" by looking on Wikipedia or other such sources that can be manipulated.

Comment: "The trouble with quotes on the Internet is that it's difficult to determine whether or not they are genuine." - Abraham Lincoln

Comment: That's right, and the point of it is: What if my friend works in a newspaper and tells me when he has a partner abusing the wikipedia so I can ignore his/her articles? This should work in a similar way: You can rate with full accuracy one particular source, but coarse accuracy on a number of sources should be enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an interesting project that can be as simple/complicated as you want it to be.

#### Simple Version

- Manually create a white-list of sources.
- Do look-ups for the target phrase and orator in those sources.

(possible source: http://thinkexist.com)

#### More Complicated

- Create a white-list and black-list of sources.
- Do a search for the target.
- For the pages that contain the target, determine if they are more similar to your white-list sources or your black-list of sources.

(You will need to create a method for getting the similarity between two web-pages.)

#### Still More Complicated

Use Supervised Machine Learning:

- Start by manually labeling some web pages as reliable, unreliable, or in-between.
- Train a Machine Learning system on that training data.
- Now the Machine Learning system can predict the category of new web pages.

#### Still More Complicated++

Actually write the Supervised Machine Learning system yourself, based on several methods and compare the results.

#### Another Idea

Use a Supervised Machine Learning system to report whether or not the target phrase seems reliable by itself, without looking for any other sources.

#### The Whole 9 Yards

Use an Unsupervised Machine Learning Learning system to build up a collection of white-list/black-list web pages based on just a couple of seed keywords or phrases.

#### The Whole 10 Yards (Why do people only want to go 9?)

Write your own Unsupervised system, perhaps based on boot-strapping.

#### Some final thoughts

I would recommend starting at simple and moving up.

Also, build a testing apparatus that lets you calculate how well a particular solution works, that way you can compare the different approaches.

You will likely want to record how many False-Positives, Positive-Positives, False-Negatives, Negative-Negatives and Undecideds that your system reports.

That way you can determine Accuracy and Recall, and evaluate your systems.

I would assume that the simple approach would give high accuracy and low recall.

But that the more complicated methods could yield a system that is much faster than a human at verification, but which doesn't do quite as well as a human.

#### Last Things

The problem is an old one and nearly impossible to achieve perfection.

It reminded me of a few pages I read recently:

- [Munchhausen Trilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_Trilemma)
- [Turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)
- [Quis Custodiet Ipsos Custodes?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quis_custodiet_ipsos_custodes%3F)
- [Invalid Proof Techniques](http://school.maths.uwa.edu.au/~berwin/humour/invalid.proofs.html)

Comment: Awesome answer, if only for the really interesting references you make. I guess I will have a bad time with the supervised machine learning techniques but otherwise I think it's something I can approach. Thanks a lot.